# Xamarin UITest: How to select a string in a NumberPicker on Android

Tags: xamarin.uitest

Our app has NumberPickers in different places with all string values. I want to select the value using the string value rather than the integer value. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried 
app.Query(x => x.Class("EditText").Invoke("setText", "cat"));
it actually sets the text but when saving the value it reverts back to the original selection.

I don't want to use the following code as it sets the value using the integer value. 
app.Query(x=>x.Class("NumberPicker").Invoke("setValue", 2))
It would be nice if anybody could help me select the value in the NumberPicker using the string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've opened the Number Picker, on Android you can use the following code to select a NumberPicker value using the string value (example using the Xamarin Forms Gallery app):

```
app.ScrollDownTo(m => m.Text("White"), x => x.Id("select_dialog_listview"));
app.Tap(x => x.Text("White"));
Assert.IsTrue(app.Query("PickerControl")[0].Text == "White");
```